# How to write a get function in flutter with route as well as a variable

Tags: flutter, dart, frontend, backend

so i have this function in my backend..

````
```
Route::get('/geteachemp/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\EmployeeLeaveController@geteempleave');```
````

where i pass in the route and an id so it only gives this that particular information with that specific id..it works well in my reactjs  api made whereby i call it like this

````
```const getleaves = async (id) => {
        axios.get("geteachempleave/" + id).then(res => {
            if (res.status === 200) {
                setleavedata(res.data)
                //setLoading(false);
            }
        })
    };```
````

any idea how can i do the same ting with flutter..rn this is my get function on flutter

````
```_getNews() {
    CallApi().getPublicData("getempleave").then((response) {
      setState(() {
        Iterable list = json.decode(response.body);
        news = list.map((model) => Myrecord2.fromJson(model)).toList();
      });
    });
  }```
````

how can i also pass in id thea with the route like i did inreactjs.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add the http package

```yaml
dependencies:
  http: <latest_version>
```

Import the http package.

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

Additionally, in your AndroidManifest.xml file, add the Internet permission.

```xml
<!-- Required to fetch data from the internet. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

2. Make a network request

```dart
Future<http.Response> fetchAlbum() {
  return http.get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1'));
}
```

if nothing of that works you might consider reading the full [article](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data).